# How can I make this type of draw-able shape, android?

Tags: android, xml, drawable, shapes

I need to make this shape in android using the shape xml

[image]

The shape needs to be in rectangle shape with round corners at top left and top right leaving the bottom corners as it is.

I tried the following but not working

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" 
      />
    <gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="@color/Red"
    android:startColor="@color/Red"
    android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />

    <corners
       android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:topRightRadius="4dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="5dip"
        android:left="10dip"
        android:right="10dip"
        android:top="5dip" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

set `<corners>` like in `XML`

```
<corners 
   android:radius="1dp" 
   android:topLeftRadius="10dp" 
   android:topRightRadius="10dp" 
   android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"    
   android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
```